# Programmatically Recursively Make Directory

Tags: c, directory, mkdir

I want my program to create a file located at the path of the command parameter, i.e. `program /home/user/directory/that/doesnt/exist/file`. If the directory doesn't exist, `fopen` will fail to open the file, so the program would have to create the directories. Would I have to program my own loop to detect each slash and `mkdir` each directory or is there a function to do this automatically?

Comment: More modern languages than C typically come with frameworks that offer exactly this sort of functionality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone coded it for you: [mkpath()](http://niallohiggins.com/2009/01/08/mkpath-mkdir-p-alike-in-c-for-unix/)

Or if you're satisfied using `system()`, then you can use `system("mkdir -p /your/path/here");`

Comment: The `system` solution is missing its mandatory boilerplate warning.